# Android app performance on Android Studio (Updated from Gradle 1.5 to 2.2.3)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I got performance issues when I updated Android Studio. I found the line that makes the difference `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'`, if I use gradle:1.5.0 execution time is 2s if I use updated 2.2.3 time is 3.2s. Why is newer version slower?

- Using `build:gradle:1.5.0`:

[image: build:gradle:1.5.0]

- Using `build:gradle:2.2.3`:

[image: build:gradle:2.2.3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is mostly because of bugs and the new Android Studio testing out new features.

Answer (score 0):

change the jcenter() to mavenCentral() to get back < 3 seconds.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: tested with mavenCentral() and jcenter() made no change on emulator or phone.
i couldn't change gradle to 2.0.0. android studio reported some error, tested with 2.2.3